# Custom Android Layouts

Tags: android

I have an upcoming project that requires me to make a custom layout. I have been looking all over for a way to complete this but with no success. The layout will have custom buttons that need to fit the screen and some other custom views. In other words I need it to look the same on all types of devices. So these custom views need to stretch to fit the screens. Something similar to the weather bug app but the buttons will be at the top and there won't be so many options. The buttons will fit the screen width wise. Basically the layout will not contain any stock UI.

I would like to have a book or tutorial that I could follow to help me out here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

check out this blog: http://blog.stylingandroid.com/

there are a lot of good examples for every kind of layout manager in Android.

Furthermore I strongly recommend to you to have a look in the Android's API Demo and source code.

For creating custom view, that's the best resource: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html

good luck!

Comment: the basic approach is, that you have to extend one of existing android.view.View classes, for example ImageView or RelativeLayout. It depends on your custom view, how much logic you put into it and in your code. However, you can then use your custom view for declaration within XML. For that you have to provide the whole class name of your view, ie your class has the class name com.wilson.view.MyImageView you can declare it in XML like the following: <com.wilson.view.MyImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content" ... />